# How to avoid mixing terminal-input with user-input?

Tags: c, linux, io

I currently get the cursor position in the terminal like so:

```
coordinates getCursorPos() {
  char buf[1];
  char data[64];
  int y, x;
  char cmd[] = "\033[6n";
  coordinates cursor_pos = {.x = -1, .y = -1};
  struct termios oldattr, newattr;

  tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &oldattr);
  newattr = oldattr;
  newattr.c_lflag &= ~(ICANON | ECHO);
  newattr.c_cflag &= ~(CREAD);
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &newattr);

  write(STDIN_FILENO, cmd, sizeof(cmd));
  read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);

  if (*buf == '\033') {
    read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);
    if (*buf == '[') {
      read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);
      for (int i = 0; *buf != 'R'; i++) {
        data[i] = *buf;
        read(STDIN_FILENO, buf, 1);
      }
      // check if string matches expected data
      int valid = sscanf(data, "%d;%d", &y, &x);
      if (valid == 2) {
        cursor_pos.x = x;
        cursor_pos.y = y;
      }
    }
  }
  tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &oldattr);
  return cursor_pos;
}
```

but even though I also disable echoing and set the other options so that the `cmd` won't show up in stdout but sometimes when I press a lot of stuff almost simultaneously I still see some of the cmd-output-fragment, that I want to parse, in my stdout. How can I separate these commands to not be seen in my terminal? Even when I try to clean (ie empty stdin) it still shows up sometimes.

Comment: It isn't entirely clear what you are trying to do.  As near as I can make out, you are trying to send a command to the terminal so it reports it size back.  However, you are also dealing with what the user might have typed that is not yet read, and what the user might type between the time your function starts operations and finishes.  Dealing with what's already in the buffer is nigh-on intractable, I fear.  You can clear that out ([`tcflush()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/tcflush.html)) but throwing away user input like that is not a particularly good idea.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler No the command I'm sending writes the current cursor position in the terminal to stdin which I then parse. However this return sequence I'm parsing also sometimes shows up in my stdout screen which I dont understand since I read and write everything to stdin which is in non-echo mode. I already tried with flushing the stream but for some reason it still gets through sometimes

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps, in terminal I use `stty -echo` to prevent user input shown. (sorry, I can't comment)